# How to extract n characters from a string of undefined length using regex in varnish?

Tags: varnish-vcl

I am writing a varnish module (VCL) for my backend server. It requires a logic of extracting n characters from a string of undefined length.

I tried regsub() function of vcl with a regex to replace part of the string with empty space.

I need to extract first 20 characters of string. When the string length is 36, i used regex to replace last 16 characters to empty space. 
But when length of the string is undefined say 40. i get 24 characters instead of 20. How do i achieve this?

```
set req.http.mysubstr = regsub(req.http.mystring, ".{16}$", "");
```

```
set req.http.mysubstr = regsub(req.http.mystring, ".{($variable)}$", ""); # $variable should be the length of the string - first 20 characters
```

Answer (score 1):

Use capturing groups:

```
regsub(req.http.mystring, "^(.{20}).*", "\1")
```

test it on regex101.com